# Randomly select item from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON string like this :

```
[{"Format":"I25","Content":"172284201241"},  {"Format":"I25","Content":"40124139"},
{"Format":"I25","Content":"20197086185689"},
{"Format":"I25","Content":"10215887"},
{"Format":"I25","Content":"702666712272"},
{"Format":"QRCODE","Content":"3"}]
```

and I just want to select one of these items randomly,for example :

```
{"Format":"I25","Content":"40124139"}
```

How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: $a = ['bla', 'bla', 'bla']; $a[ rand(0, count($a)-1) ];

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83611/what-does-randomically-mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That string looks a lot like JSON, so decode it into an array.

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
```

Then, pick a random index:

```
$one_item = $array[rand(0, count($array) - 1)];
```

and finally convert back to JSON:

```
$one_item_string = json_encode($one_item);
echo $one_item_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the array element as PHP assoc array use:

```
$string = '[{"Format":"I25","Content":"172284201241"},  {"Format":"I25","Content":"40124139"},
{"Format":"I25","Content":"20197086185689"},
{"Format":"I25","Content":"10215887"},
{"Format":"I25","Content":"702666712272"},
{"Format":"QRCODE","Content":"3"}]';

$result = array_rand(json_decode($string, true));
```

If you want the string encode it back:

```
$result = json_encode(array_rand(json_decode($string, true)));
```

Comment: `array_rand` only returns the key of the array entry. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the json to a PHP array, and then randomly pick an element from the array:

```
$json = '[{"Format":"I25","Content":"172284201241"},  {"Format":"I25","Content":"40124139"},
{"Format":"I25","Content":"20197086185689"},
{"Format":"I25","Content":"10215887"},
{"Format":"I25","Content":"702666712272"},
{"Format":"QRCODE","Content":"3"}]';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$element = $arr[mt_rand(0, count($arr) - 1)];

// optionally convert back to json
$json = json_encode($element);
```